# Circular dependency issue in ARM template for Cosmos DB with encryption

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I want to create an ARM template for encrypted CosmosDB by customer managed key

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    ...
},
"functions": [],
"variables": {
    ...
},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
        "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
        "name": "[variables('keyVaultName')]",
        "location": "westeurope",
        "properties": {
            "sku": {
                "family": "A",
                "name": "Standard"
            },
            "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('dbAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "accessPolicies": [
                {
                    "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
                    "objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('dbAccountName')), '2021-03-01-preview', 'full').identity.principalId]",
                    "permissions": {
                        "keys": [
                            "get",
                            "wrapKey",
                            "unwrapKey"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "enabledForDeployment": false,
            "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
            "enabledForTemplateDeployment": false,
            "enableSoftDelete": true,
            "softDeleteRetentionInDays": 90,
            "enableRbacAuthorization": false,
            "vaultUri": "[concat('https://', variables('keyVaultName'), '.vault.azure.net/')]",
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "enablePurgeProtection": true
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys",
        "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
        "name": "[concat(variables('keyVaultName'), '/', variables('keyVaultName'), '-cosmos-db')]",
        "location": "westeurope",
        "dependsOn": [
           "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('keyVaultName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "crv": "P-256",
            "kty": "EC",
            "key_size": 4096,
            "keyOps": [
                "wrapKey",
                "unwrapKey"
            ],
            "attributes": {
                "enabled": true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
        "name": "[variables('dbAccountName')]",
        "apiVersion": "2021-01-15",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "kind": "MongoDB",
        "identity": {
            "type": "SystemAssigned"
        },
        "properties": {
            "consistencyPolicy": "[variables('consistencyPolicy')[parameters('defaultConsistencyLevel')]]",
            "locations": "[variables('locations')]",
            "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
            "apiProperties": {
                "serverVersion": "[parameters('serverVersion')]"
            },
            "keyVaultKeyUri": "[concat('https://', variables('keyVaultName'), '.vault.azure.net/keys/', variables('keyVaultName'), '-cosmos-db')]"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys', variables('keyVaultName'), concat(variables('keyVaultName'), '-cosmos-db'))]"
        ]
    }
],
"outputs": {
    ...
}
```

}

I was trying approach with nested template but getting such error after deployment: "DatabaseAccount name '****' already exists"

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    ...
},
"functions": [],
"variables": {
    ...
},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
        "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
        "name": "[variables('keyVaultName')]",
        "location": "westeurope",
        "properties": {
            "sku": {
                "family": "A",
                "name": "Standard"
            },
            "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('dbAccountName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('appName'))]"
            ],
            "accessPolicies": [
                {
                    "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
                    "objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('dbAccountName')), '2021-03-01-preview', 'full').identity.principalId]",
                    // "objectId": "d8749310-a50e-457e-97cb-c6e8ea601eb9",
                    "permissions": {
                        "keys": [
                            "get",
                            "wrapKey",
                            "unwrapKey"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "enabledForDeployment": false,
            "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
            "enabledForTemplateDeployment": false,
            "enableSoftDelete": true,
            "softDeleteRetentionInDays": 90,
            "enableRbacAuthorization": false,
            "vaultUri": "[concat('https://', variables('keyVaultName'), '.vault.azure.net/')]",
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "enablePurgeProtection": true
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys",
        "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
        "name": "[concat(variables('keyVaultName'), '/', variables('keyVaultName'), '-cosmos-db')]",
        "location": "westeurope",
        // "dependsOn": [
        //     "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('keyVaultName'))]"
        // ],
        "properties": {
            "crv": "P-256",
            "kty": "EC",
            "key_size": 4096,
            "keyOps": [
                "wrapKey",
                "unwrapKey"
            ],
            "attributes": {
                "enabled": true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
        "name": "[variables('dbAccountName')]",
        "apiVersion": "2021-01-15",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "kind": "MongoDB",
        "identity": {
            "type": "SystemAssigned"
        },
        "properties": {
            "consistencyPolicy": "[variables('consistencyPolicy')[parameters('defaultConsistencyLevel')]]",
            "locations": "[variables('locations')]",
            "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
            "apiProperties": {
                "serverVersion": "[parameters('serverVersion')]"
            }
            // "keyVaultKeyUri": "[concat('https://', variables('keyVaultName'), '.vault.azure.net/keys/', variables('keyVaultName'), '-cosmos-db')]"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys', variables('keyVaultName'), concat(variables('keyVaultName'), '-cosmos-db'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
        "name": "databaseUpdate",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys', variables('keyVaultName'), concat(variables('keyVaultName'), '-cosmos-db'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "template": {
                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "resources": [

                    {
                        "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
                        "name": "[variables('dbAccountName')]",
                        "apiVersion": "2021-01-15",
                        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                        "kind": "MongoDB",
                        "identity": {
                            "type": "SystemAssigned"
                        },
                        "properties": {
                            "consistencyPolicy": "[variables('consistencyPolicy')[parameters('defaultConsistencyLevel')]]",
                            "locations": "[variables('locations')]",
                            "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
                            "apiProperties": {
                                "serverVersion": "[parameters('serverVersion')]"
                            },
                            "keyVaultKeyUri": "[concat('https://', variables('keyVaultName'), '.vault.azure.net/keys/', variables('keyVaultName'), '-cosmos-db')]"
                        }
                    },

                    {
                        "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases",
                        "name": "[concat(variables('dbAccountName'), '/', variables('dbName'))]",
                        "apiVersion": "2021-01-15",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/', variables('dbAccountName'))]"
                        ],
                        "properties": {
                            "resource": {
                                "id": "[variables('dbName')]"
                            },
                            "options": {
                                "throughput": "[parameters('throughput')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {
    ...
}
```

}

I was also trying to create key vault resource and key vault access policy separately. But getting exception

> {"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Access policies operation not permitted. Allowed operations are "add", "replace", and "remove"."}]}

Comment: Remove the dependsOn reference to the Cosmos DB account in the key vault resource. This will fix the circular reference.

Comment: @MarkBrown thanks for your suggestion but even if I remove dependsOn from key vault I still have circular dependency in key vault. In case if I remove all dependesOn database created but key vault don't and database can't be deployed as encrypted key not found

Comment: Make sure you keep the dependsOn within the databaseAccount resource back to the keyvault key so that it waits until the key vault and key are created first. I also don't understand why you have a deployment resource in your arm template. If you are creating these resources for the first time you do not need that. If you can't get that to work I find it can be helpful to create the resources in the portal then export the template to figure out what I did wrong

Comment: Regarding the process, first, we create azure cosmos db and enable MSI; second, we configure access policy for MSI in azure key vault; thrid, configure encryption. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-cmk

Comment: I've done this with both Cognitive Services (https://gist.github.com/heaths/e3e154ac9c0f5e007c39f0ed87915087) and another service and the nested deployment works. I'm curious, if you just try to redeploy a template with a Cosmos DB resource (nothing else), does it incrementally deploy? Wonder if the resource provider has an issue with redeployment regardless of ARM templates.